# When refreshing with JavaScript, PHP is losing its data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using this JavaScript code to refresh my div.

This is in my index.php

```
<div class="kita" id="kita"><?php include('progress.tpl');?></div>
```

This is also in my index.php. I'm using this code to refresh my div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
     $('#kita').load('/template/progress.tpl').fadeIn("slow");
 }, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

This is my progress.tpl

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?=$user['exppoints']; ?>"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?=$user['exppoints']/1000*2; ?>%">
    <?=$user['exppoints']; ?>/50000
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get this script to refresh every second but after it refresh the code goes too this in inspect element.

```
<div class="kita" id="kita">
 <div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?=$user['exppoints']; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?=$user['exppoints']/1000*2; ?>%">
    <!--?=$user['exppoints']; ?-->/50000
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If someone have solution, and can share it with me that would be awesome.

Comment: Why aren't you using the smarty syntax?

Comment: for that you have to store data in cookie

Comment: Thank you for you'r reply guys. More help need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you try to access the template file directly, it is 1) not being parsed by PHP because it is a .tpl file and your server is apparently not configured to parse .tpl files as PHP and 2) even if it was parsed by PHP or simply a .php file, all of the variables would be undefined.

Here's a simple example:

page.php:

```
<?php

$myVar = 5;

include('out.php');

?>
```

out.php

```
<?php

echo 'The number is ' . $myVar;

?>
```

Output from page.php:

> The number is 5

Output from out.php:

> The number is

... because $myVar is not set when out.php is run by itself.

You need to take a different approach, such as having JavaScript load a PHP file that both a) sets the variables needed by the template and b) includes the template.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir. It's parsered my whole website is using .tpl. Could you make script like that if there is no problem or give me link so I can check it out? Thank you